# How to get css of multicolumn css3 by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="multicolum">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #multicolumn
    {
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-gap: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
   }
```

How can I get attribute "column-gap" of muticomlum by javascript not jquery. Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

change the id of div into multicolumn and then:

`document.getElementById("multicolumn").style.columnGap` will return the `column-gap` css property

Comment: It return undefine. Please help me!

Comment: got it, the problem is the id of the div. you misspelled it correct it to multicolumn. After modification it should work. I will edit the ans